# Increase users in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need in Jmeter increase a group of user. For example, increase 10 users every 20 seconds.

Somebody knows how to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve that,

1. If you want to test with total 100 users with 10 users coming up in every 20 seconds then you can set your ramp up as 200 seconds

   Ramp up : 200 seconds

   Total users : 100

   This will start 10 users every 20 seconds which you need. (In this no external plugin is required)
2. Use stepping thread group which allows similar functionality. you can get from [Stepping Thread group - JMeter plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/)

Answer (score 1):

Check http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/.

You have to install http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/file/JMeterPlugins-Standard-1.2.0.zip for that.